# PHP5 mysqli vs mysql config files

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, web

I know this sounds very stupid indeed, but I find mysqli prepared statements and its object-oriented approach attractive so I plan on converting some of my past doodles from mysql to mysqli.

***Here it is... The question***

In mysql I used to have a configuration file, for example included in every file that needs the database (i.e. `require('sys/dbconfig.php');`)

I am not sure if I need to do this in mysqli, or do so as others say, open a connection when you need it, close it when you don't need it (i.e. stick `$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);` everywhere it needs database transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like that:

config.php

```
define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("DB_NAME", "demo");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "root");
```

database.php

```
// include database constants
include_once("config.php");                   

// create db connection
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

now you can make SQL statements via

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT x FROM y;");
```

Comment: Ohhh great idea :P It's just what I am guessing for, Have the global constants defined in config and open/close connections everywhere where you need it :) is that correct?

Comment: In this case, i would create the $db in the beginning of your script/app and use $db whereever you need it. php will use the same database connection every time ($db is ONE connection).. (or have i misunderstood your question ?)

Answer (score 0):

`MySqlI` comes in 2 flavours: *procedural* and *object oriented*.

When you use the *procedural* style everything *stays the same as in mysqli_*.
You are refering to the *object oriented* style and there the configuration is different .. more object oriented actually. That means that you have to create a new instance of mysqli and use its methods to get the job done.

Note: when using mysqli_ the same way as mysql you will have the same problems with SQL injection. You should use mysqli in combination with prepared queries and parameter binding.

Comment: So do I include a config file once like how things are done in the past or do I open connections when I needed and close it when I don't?

Comment: if you want to use procedural style: yes. See my warning about SQL injection!

Comment: yes I meant I am looking forward to preparedStatements ;) I've been using mysql_real_escape_string like crazy in the past which I find very inconvenient. So how would I be able to do it OO-style with mysqli? Open a connection when I needed and close it when it's finished? ditch the config files and bring the connection code to the application level?

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli opens the connection when it is instantiated with `new mysqli(...)` (so does PDO).

During a PHP session you should not need to open/close **connections** to the database because the duration of a PHP session (for normal websites/webapps) is less than 1 second.

Forcing the equivalent of mysql_connect/mysql_close multiple times in the code can be helpful only in long running scripts that do not need an active connection for their entire duration.

The number of separate mysql connections allowed per mysql user is limited depending on the configuration of you server.

If you have some script that runs a long time and that will likely intersect many other scripts, you may use-up all of the allowed connections per user and thus block other users.

I would suggest (as a simple approach) to instantiate mysqli in a file that you will include everywhere you need db access use the variable you stored the mysqli object everywhere you need it using `global $db`.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to create constants in a config file like Panique does.

I also create an App class with a static method `fetch_db` that contains the code for the connection. Then whenever I need a db connection I just call `App::fetch_db()`.

I can post the code and a little more explanation later this afternoon when I get home.